# NavigationStack; View contents below navigation area(s)

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationbar, swiftui-navigationstack

I have a simple view that is somewhere in my navigationstack hierarchy. But the content is below the navigation areas top and bottom. How to solve this?
I have not set to ignore safearea edges. What is causing this?

```
struct PrivacyView: View {
    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        Text("App Privacy Statement")
                            .padding(.top)
                            .font(.title2)
                        
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Image(uiImage: AppImages.gameDefaultImage)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                            
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding()
                        
                        Text(Bundle.getText("privacy"))
                            .padding()
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .strokeBorder(.orange, lineWidth: 2)
                    )
                    .padding()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(
            LinearGradient(colors: [
                Color.systemOrange,
                Color.systemPurple,
                Color.systemPurple,
                Color.systemPurple,
                Color.systemPurple
            ], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The view presenting this view added a frame modifier to the view on instantiating. Modifier removed, problem solved!